# Espresso Mock Web Server not waiting OkHttp Idling Resource with Dagger Hilt

Tags: android, android-espresso, okhttp, dagger-hilt, mockwebserver

I am trying to write UI test for my Fragments with `Espresso` and `MockWebServer`. I am using `OkHttp Idling Resource` to tell Espresso to wait for the API calls to complete.

But somehow, sometimes my tests are working but sometimes not, because `Espresso` does its job before service request. So my recyclerView item click test fail.

I can not figure out why espresso does not wait for the API calls? Can anyone help?

**Here is my test class**

```
@MediumTest
@HiltAndroidTest
@UninstallModules(PersistenceModule::class, NetworkModule::class)
class MainFragmentTest {

    @get:Rule
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    private val mockWebServer = MockWebServer()

    @Inject
    lateinit var okHttp3IdlingResource: OkHttp3IdlingResource

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        hiltRule.inject()
        // Prepare Mock Web Server
        mockWebServer.start(8080)
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(okHttp3IdlingResource)
    }

    @Test
    fun mainFragmentTest(){

        // Prepare Mock Web Server
        mockWebServer.dispatcher = object : Dispatcher() {
            override fun dispatch(request: RecordedRequest): MockResponse {
                return MockResponse()
                    .setResponseCode(200)
                    .setBody(MockResponseFileReader("post_success.json").content)
            }
        }

        val navController = mockk<NavController>(relaxed = true)

        launchFragmentInHiltContainer<MainFragment> {
            Navigation.setViewNavController(requireView(), navController)
        }

        onView(withId(R.id.rv_posts)).perform(
            RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition<PostViewHolder>(
                0,
                click()
            )
        )


        verify { navController.navigate(MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToDetailFragment().setPost(any())) }
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        mockWebServer.close()
    }

}
```

**Here is my `TestNetworkModule` that holds network dependencies**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object TestNetworkModule {

    /**
     * Provides [OkHttpClient] instance
     */
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideOkHttpClient() : OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
    }

    /**
     * Provides [OkHttp3IdlingResource] instance
     */
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideIdlingResource(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient) : OkHttp3IdlingResource {
        return OkHttp3IdlingResource.create(
            "okhttp",
            okHttpClient
        )
    }

    /**
     * Provides [Retrofit] instance
     */
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient) : Retrofit {
        val contentType = "application/json".toMediaType()
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://127.0.0.1:8080")
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(Json.asConverterFactory(contentType))
            .build()
    }

    /**
     * Provides [ApiService] instance
     */
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApiService(retrofit: Retrofit): ApiService {
        return retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
    }

}
```

I do not know what I am missing so any help will be appreciated

Current Versions;

```
androidTestImplementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.6.0"
androidTestImplementation 'com.jakewharton.espresso:okhttp3-idling-resource:1.0.0'
```

Comment: Curious, how does your `OkHttp3IdlingResource` class look like?

Comment: It comes from `com.jakewharton.espresso:okhttp3-idling-resource` library @Aaron I provide it in my `TestNetworkModule`

Comment: My best guess is that your idling resource isn't being registered correctly. I'd confirm this by adding a delay to your network responses and seeing that it always fails (since it would hopefully remove the possibility for a race condition). I'd then try setting up your idling resources as a test rule instead of how you have: https://medium.com/insiden26/okhttp-idling-resource-for-espresso-462ef2417049

Comment: @agoff so you mean, should I use test rule for register `OkHttp Idling Resource`. If so how can I inject `OkHttpClient` to rule?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure you'd need to, but I think you could set up your `OkHttpIdlingResourceRule` to take in an `OkHttpClient` and use that instead of `OkHttpProvider.instance` when declaring the resource.

Comment: Yes, but this way I do not know how pass the `OkHttp` instance to rule that I provided in `TestNetworkModule` @agoff

Comment: Is it failing when you run a single test or a set of tests?

Comment: Both @Anatolii I tried with single and multiple

Comment: @ysfcyln it would be nice if you could create a sample project on github for this. I cannot see the problem so far.

Comment: It would be very nice but unfortunately it is not possible for now :(  @Anatolii

Comment: @ysfcyln btw, you never unregister your `okHttp3IdlingResource`, at least it's not shown anywhere in your code.

Comment: @ysfcyln, did you get the solution for the above one, as i am also facing the similar issue, could you please assist me

Comment: @Reprator unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution so instead of  `MockWebServer` I used `fake repository` approach

Comment: @ysfcyln, i had to use idling resource alongwith that, now working for me,

Comment: I suppose Espresso sometimes moves out of the idling state while data is still being processed. So you have a race condition where your tests will assert before the data actually has been shown on screen.

Comment: Do you have EarlyEntryPoint implemented in your dagger setup?